# Macbook pro 15" 2015 wireless dropping out from time to time

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, macbook

So I just got a `macbook pro (earlier this year)` and I've started to notice that my internet is dropping out quite frequently. The wireless is still connected but the actual internet itself stops working for about 20-30 seconds. So often I'll have to manually disconnect from the wifi and then reconnect.

I know there's nothing wrong with my `wifi router` because this never happens on any other device in my home. My router is also connected to a steady 30mpb cable connection. Also when I open my `macbook` it seems to take 20-30 seconds to connect to the internet!? I use to have a 2012 macbook pro and my internet would connect as soon as I open my lid.

Has anyone else had this problem? Could there be something wrong with my macbook? Should I take it into apple?

Comment: Did you put 10.11 on it? There have been some issues with wireless drivers on that, or so I hear (10.9 and clinging like a clam to a working system that does not look like an iPhone puked all over my Mac screen.)

Comment: Yeah I've got `10.11` on it. Should I update to `10.11.1`?

Comment: ... or head back to 10.10.5 if you have a backup from before you upgraded.

Comment: unfortunately you can't run a good OS on that laptop - only 10.10 or 10.11.. both are terribly buggy..   i'd suggest doing an SMC reset on that machine - -it may resolve the issues (albeit that's a low chance, in my opinion)...  your next shot would be to reinstall to the oldest OS you can install on the system.